# How can I use an .htaccess redirect for a partial path?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I had to adjust some paths on my site and I need to use .htaccess to redirect the items on the chance a user accesses the old url.

For example my old urls (relative) could be:

```
/old-path/page1.php
/old-path/page2.php
/old-path/page3.php
etc...
```

I had to change the path (for this example) to new-path and I need to adjust the .htaccess so anyone that comes to any page with .../old-path/... will be redirected to

```
.../new-path/...
```

Also, would this satisfy the 301 or would I need to list out each page?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use either mod+alias:

```
Redirect 301 /old-path /new-path
```

or using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?old-path/(.*)$ /new-path/$1 [L,R=301]
```

These could be in the htaccess file in your document root or in the server/vhost config. If you already have rewrite rules somewhere, you may just want to stick with mod_rewrite because redirecting with mod_alias while using mod_rewrite can sometimes give conflicting results.

Comment: I ended up using the RewriteRule optoin

Comment: If you want to make one-to-one redirects - use `Redirect` for anything more generic or variable => use `RewriteRule`, be aware, on certain hosts following **can** cause **redirect loop**:  `Redirect 301 /index.html /` (`index.html` specifically)