# How can i redirect a URL to new URL by editing htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For example
**Old URL :** https://www.example.com/first/second/third/FILE_NAME 
**New URL :** https://www.newdomain/new_path/FILE_NAME

So what i want is that wherever **Old URL** is found in the page just replace it with **New URL** except its FILE_NAME

Tried :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/templates/test1/default/update/mach4/cache/default/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://cdn.example.com/new-folder/ [R=301,L]
```

Live example :
my old url is 
 https://www.tracker.com/templates/applications/default/themes/default/logo.png

new URL should be 
 https://cdn.tracker-files.com/tracker-cdn/logo.png

except file name whole url need to be changed (just like string replace function)

Comment: what have you tried? show your current .htaccess and point out what part doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @Jeff comment edited. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

try this tuto in [medium](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file) , or give us your htaccess file code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568165/how-can-i-use-an-htaccess-redirect-for-a-partial-path

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RedirectMatch` .

To redirect `example.com/first/second/third/file` to `newdomain.com/first/second/third/file` you can use the following Redirect in your `example.com/.htaccess` .

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/first/second/third/file$ http://newdomain.com/new_path/file
```

If you have more then one url of the same format , you can use regular expressions instead of the URI.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/(.+) $ http://newdomain.com/new_folder/$1
```

The above will redirect `example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/thisfile` to `newdomain.com/new_folder/thisfile` .

Comment: see Live example in my question