# How do I redirect all requests to a subpath to another URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a folder in which I store user profile pages. For example, the profile page for the user "JohnDoe" is:

```
mywebsite.com/user/JohnDoe/index.php
```

I want to redirect all requests to `mywebsite.com/user/*/index.php` to `mywebsite.com/user/index.php`.

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568165/how-can-i-use-an-htaccess-redirect-for-a-partial-path) and tried redirecting to google.com as a test:

```
Redirect 301 /user google.com
```

but this redirects to `mywebsite.com/google.com/JohnDoe/index.php`.

I then cleared my browser's cache and tried:

```
Redirect 301 /user https://www.google.com
```

Simply put, I am looking for something like:

```
Redirect 301 /user/*/index.php /user/index.php
```

but I am not getting redirected. Unfortunately I couldn't find this in the forums. How do I accomplish this, **without** the existence of the user profile page?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

put this code in .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^OLDDOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://NEWDOMAIN.com [R=301,L]
```

from http://www.webconfs.com/154/301-redirects-how-to-redirect-your-website/

Comment: Hoou should I modify the second-to-last line such that it redirects from `mywebsite.com/users/*/index.html`, where `*` can be anything composed of only letters/numbers?